# The error that I get is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have been working on a script on Python with pandas but I have no previous experience using the library.

I have been following a tutorial to complete this but this part of my code doesn't seem to be working(maybe outdated syntax) despite the instructions.

***The error that I get is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date':***

```
def get_search_console_data(webproperty, days=-365):
  if webproperty is not None:
    query = webproperty.query.range(start='today', days=days).dimension('date', 'query')
    r = query.get()
    df = pd.DataFrame(r.rows)
    return df

  print("Web property doesn't exist, please select a valid one from this list")
  print(account.webproperties)

df = get_search_console_data(webproperty)
     

    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

    df[df["date"] > "2021-10-3"]

last_day_queries = df[df["date"] > "2021-10-3"]["query"]
rest_of_queries = df[df["date"] < "2021-10-3"]["query"]
```

Comment: what if webproperty is None? You don't return anything and df = None.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `webproperty` which you are passing to the `get_search_console_data()` function, is `None` that makes the function return `NoneType` (actually nothing).
Check whether `webproperty` is `None` or not.
Otherwise the `df` which is being made in the function is `None`.

Comment: hey, thanks for you input! As I said I am following a tutorial so I am not sure how to modificate it. As a matter of fact, in my case webproperty is not None. Could you give me some idea how to do it?

Comment: If `webproperty` is not None, could you please show the  result of `print(webproperty)`? @user16394386

Comment: there isn't one, the code we were given is what I have put above

Comment: If you have only the code above; then it is not even initialized the `webproperty` varaible. shouldn't it be initialized? @user16394386

Comment: oh sorry! I thought you meant inside the function. here is the rest of the webproperty code; domain_name = "https://www.forpen.it/"

**#Insert your domain name below.**
`webproperty = account['www.forpen.it']`------> this was initially set to `webproperty = account[domain_name]` but I have changed it, dont know if it is right this either.

Comment: What is `account` variable? Is it a `list`? Could you please give the `account` variable, too?

Comment: sure, it is not a list **account = searchconsole.authenticate(client_config='/Users/tv/Downloads/client_secret_9.com.json')**

Comment: please `print(account)`, to see the output. and send it to me @user16394386

Comment: thanks for helping, this is the output,** <searchconsole.account.Account(client_id='993908086254-ajbb6sknf5pn49ke39rs09vs0pfvvqj0.apps.googleusercontent.com')>**

Comment: Apparently it is an Object. Please check what `print(account['forpen.it])` or `print(account['www.forprn.it'])` returns. and again send it here. @user16394386

Comment: those two return **None** but if I leave it as `webproperty = account[domain_name]` where domain_name has previously been defined as www.forpen.it (as per my comment above), I get `<searchconsole.account.WebProperty(url='https://www.forpen.it/')>`

Comment: Then just leave it as it was, and check whether the code runs or not, and see if it is still giving the `NoneType` error? @user16394386

Comment: it still does, yeah

Comment: So please do this `webproperty = account[domain_name]`, this is the first step to fix it. @user16394386

Comment: and then put `print(query)` in the function, after the line `query = webproperty.query.range(start='today', days=days).dimension('date', 'query')` , and run the code, then send me what it is printed. @user16394386